# ld returned 1 exit status in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I am running this code for several hour but getting error "ld returned 1 exit status". Problem actually lye in function which are on the top nd switch which I have used at the end.

Actually it program which will preform a task of registration , login and forgot password.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void login();
void registration();
void forgot();

int main(){
    
    int c;
    
    cout<<"\t\t\t___________________________________________________________\n\n\n";
    cout<<"\t\t\t                     WELCOME TO LOGIN PAGE                 \n\n";
    cout<<"\t\t\t___________________________ MENU ___________________________\n";
    cout<<"                                                                    \n\n";
    cout<<"\t\t\t | Press 1 to LOGIN                         |"<<endl;
    cout<<"\t\t\t | Press 2 to REGISTER                      |"<<endl;
    cout<<"\t\t\t | Press 2 to if you forgot your PASSWORD   |"<<endl;
    cout<<"\t\t\t | Press 4 to EXIT                          |"<<endl;
    
    cout<<"\n\t\t\t Please enter your choice: ";
    cin>>c;
    
    switch(c){
        case 1:
            login();
            break;
        case 2:
            registration();
            break;
        case 3:
            forgot();
            break;
        case 4:
            cout<<"Thank You!";
            break;
        default:
            cout<<"Invalid Input";
    }
    
    
    
    
}
```

Comment: Where have you defined these functions? Please post a [mcve] - including the linker errors you get.

Comment: Did you link with the implementation for `login()`, `registration()` and `forgot()` ?

Answer (score 1):

This error is because the linker cannot find definitions of the function `login()`, `registration()` and `forgot()`. If the definitions are in another file, you can try including that file. if you plan to write the definitions later, you should add empty declarations of those functions.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void login();
void registration();
void forgot();

int main(){
    
    int c;
    
    cout<<"\t\t\t___________________________________________________________\n\n\n";
    cout<<"\t\t\t                     WELCOME TO LOGIN PAGE                 \n\n";
    cout<<"\t\t\t___________________________ MENU ___________________________\n";
    cout<<"                                                                    \n\n";
    cout<<"\t\t\t | Press 1 to LOGIN                         |"<<endl;
    cout<<"\t\t\t | Press 2 to REGISTER                      |"<<endl;
    cout<<"\t\t\t | Press 2 to if you forgot your PASSWORD   |"<<endl;
    cout<<"\t\t\t | Press 4 to EXIT                          |"<<endl;
    
    cout<<"\n\t\t\t Please enter your choice: ";
    cin>>c;
    
    switch(c){
        case 1:
            login();
            break;
        case 2:
            registration();
            break;
        case 3:
            forgot();
            break;
        case 4:
            cout<<"Thank You!";
            break;
        default:
            cout<<"Invalid Input";
    }
    
    
    
    
}


void login()
{

}
void registration()
{

}
void forgot()
{
     
}
```

Also, it is a good practice to use `std::cout` instead of `using namespace std`.